# Include Javascript library with @ sign in .NET core MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, yarnpkg

Currently I'm working on a .NET core MVC app wired up with yarn to add packages. So far I've added the Signalr package like this:
`yarn add @microsoft/signalr`

Which adds the package to `/wwwroot/lib/@microsoft/signalr/etc..`

However when I try to include the package in the Web app it gets stuck. I'm including it like this:
`<script src="lib/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>`

also `<script src="lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>` does not work.

Anyone knows how to fix this? We do not want to switch to libman and prefer to keep using packages with Yarn.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need know that **Yarn will not install the client side package to your wwwroot by default**.

It globally downloads the package in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Yarn\` folder.

In my PC, it exists in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6`:

[image]

### The whole working steps

1. Be sure you have installed note.js, then run following command to install Yarn :

   ```
    npm install --global yarn
   ```
2. Run command to add signalr package:

   ```
    yarn add @microsoft/signalr
   ```
3. Find the signalr package(`@microsoft` folder) in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Yarn\` and copy the whole `@microsoft` folder:

   [image]
4. Paste the whole `@microsoft` folder to your project `wwwroot/lib` folder:

   [image]
5. Then add the js reference like below:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("/lib/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js")"></script>
   ```

   [image]

---

Actually I suggest you can [use Libman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog), it can directly download to your wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the package like that in your Webclient.

Everything you want accessible from your Client must be served by your Server.

Serving a Package is a bit more tricky and I would recommend using a bundler.

With [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for example you can prepare your client Resources to be served.

In practice this can look like this:

Webpack is configured to bundle your Client Javascript and put it in `<project-root>/assets`

Your server is configured to serve every file from the `<project-root>/assets` directory to the `/assets` route.

In your client script file you import your library module like so:

```js
import {<your needed parts>} from '@microsoft/signalr';
```

Finally your html page loads your client script like so:

```html
<script src="/assets/bundle.js" type="module"></script>
```

This is a simplified example and i would recommend you to read the Webpack docs.